# Export Users, roles and grants into a CSV file

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I need to extract the users into CSV file and upload it into the role modeller to design an effective security model. Now the question arises how do I export users, roles and grants into a CSV files on MS SQL and Oracle?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle,

```
select * from dba_users

select * from table_privileges

select * from dba_roles
```

You can check these dictionary tables from: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_5081.htm#REFRN23302, or shortly from: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sys_tables/

After you get the result, with the help of any client software, you can export it to any file. For example, you can use [Toad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/toad)'s "Export Dataset" option for .csv, .xls, .txt files.

Comment: @Ygitalp Ertem: Thank for your response. How do I export these values into CSV file on Oracle.
Any idea about SQL?

Comment: @RameezXaveri You cannot do it only by writing SQL queries. Easiest way is using a software to export the results in a file. Or you can write a manual Oracle procedure(PL/SQL). Do you use any tools like PL/SQL Developer, Toad etc.? In the worst case, you can even create your CSV by copy-pasting the results. CSV is just a simple comma separated text file.